# Matrix determinant .Bad output

Tags: c, matrix

When I try to calculate a 3-order determinant of a matrix ,I received bad outputs. At the 2-order one ,it work fine. To be more specific, I don't receive 9 values (v[1,1],v[1,2] etc) ,but instead i receive more than that. I thought is a problem to arrays ,but idk.. 
Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main(void) {
    int i,j,n,i_max,j_max,ordin,i_m,j_m;
    long int det;
    int v[3][3];
    int e[3];
    int nr=0;

    printf("\nIntroduceti ordinul matricei:\t");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    if (n==2) {
        i_max=n;
        j_max=n;
        printf("\nIntroduceti valorile matricei:\n");
        for (i=1;i<=i_max;i++) {
            for (j=1;j<=j_max;j++) {
                printf("v[%d,%d]= ",i,j);
                scanf("%d",&(v[i][j]));
                nr++;
                e[nr] = v[i][j];
            }
        }

        det = (e[1]*e[4])-(e[2]*e[3]);
        printf("\nDeterminantul matricei este: %ld\n",det);
        if (det != 0) 
            printf("Matricea de ordinul %d este inversabila !",n);
            else printf("Matricea de ordinul %d nu este inversabila!",n);
    } else if (n==3) {
        i_m=n;
        j_m=n;
        printf("\nIntroduceti valorile matricei:\n");
        for (i=1; i<= i_m; i++) {
            for (j=1; j<= j_m; j++) {
                printf("v[%d,%d]= ",i,j);
                scanf("%d",&(v[i][j]));
                nr++;
                e[nr] = v[i][j];
            }
        }
        det = (e[1]*e[5]*e[9])+(e[2]*e[6]*e[7])+(e[3]*e[4]*e[8])-(e[3]*e[5]*e[7])-(e[2]*e[4]*e[9])-(e[1]*e[6]*e[8]);
        printf("Determinantul matricei este: %ld\n",det);
        if (det != 0)
            printf("Matricea de ordinul %d este inversabila!",n);
        else
            printf("Matricea de ordinul %d nu este inversabila!",n);
    } else
        printf("Ordinul matricei este incorect!");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you declare

```
int v[3][3];
int e[3];
```

There are not enough items for `e` as you use it for `v` which has 3 x 3 = 9 elements.

So it seems that it would be solved by changing the second statement to

```
int e[9];
```

but it is not the end of story.

In the `for` loops you loop nor from `0` (which is common in C language), but from `1`, so you need 1 more indices for all arrays!

So declare

```
int v[4][4];         /* for using indices from 1 to 3 */
int e[10];           /* for using indices from 1 to 9 */
```

Comment: Thank you so much . I'm kind of new in C and that seems to be a noobie mistake. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

First you say `int v[3][3];` and `int e[3];` and then you reach for elements like `v[3][3]` and `e[4]`. You seem to forget that arrays/matrices use 0-based indices. In other words, if you declare `int v[3][3];` the only elements you should refer to are `v[0][0]...v[2][2]`. When reading data into `v` the `for` loops should go from 0 to `2`, not from `1` to `3`. Also, you clearly get out of the bounds of `e`, since it has 3 elements, but you go as far as `e[9]`.

Btw, you also do not need to transfer things from `v` to `e`. After reading into `v` you can simply refer to `v[0][0]` as `v[0]`, to `v[0][1]` as `v[1]`, to `v[1][0]` as `v[3]` and to `v[2][2]` as `v[8]`.

Also, you make pretty much the same errors in the part referring to the second order determinant.

Comment: Thanks for  help :)